# Nexus 3 Upgrade broke maven deploy:deploy

Tags: maven, sonatype, nexus3

After upgrading from Nexus 2.14 to Nexus 3.x (3.4.0-02),

We now get 500 errors from our Maven jobs when we run deploy:deploy

```
Failed to transfer file: 
https://nexus.foo.net/repository/snapshots/com/foo/foo-server/1.1.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml. Return code is: 500 , ReasonPhrase:javax.servlet.ServletException: com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OCommandExecutionException: Error on execution of command: sql.select from asset where bucket = :bucket and name = :propValue?? DB name="component".
```

Besides being a security vuln to reveal an underlying DB query, the error is very opaque for us to troubleshoot something.    Anyone seen this?

The backend nexus log has this stacktrace.   Basically looks like a NPE.

```
2017-07-26 15:07:39,542-0700 WARN  [qtp871102318-2946] admin org.sonatype.nexus.repository.httpbridge.internal.ViewServlet - Failure servicing: GET /repository/snapshots/com/foo/foo-server/1.1.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OCommandExecutionException: Error on execution of command: sql.select from asset where bucket = :bucket and name = :propValue
    DB name="component"
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.OAbstractPaginatedStorage.executeCommand(OAbstractPaginatedStorage.java:3221)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.OAbstractPaginatedStorage.command(OAbstractPaginatedStorage.java:3138)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.command.OCommandRequestTextAbstract.execute(OCommandRequestTextAbstract.java:69)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.repository.storage.MetadataNodeEntityAdapter.findByProperty(MetadataNodeEntityAdapter.java:148)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.repository.storage.StorageTxImpl.findAssetWithProperty(StorageTxImpl.java:309)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.common.stateguard.SimpleMethodInvocation.proceed(SimpleMethodInvocation.java:53)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.common.stateguard.MethodInvocationAction.run(MethodInvocationAction.java:39)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.common.stateguard.StateGuard$GuardImpl.run(StateGuard.java:270)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.common.stateguard.GuardedInterceptor.invoke(GuardedInterceptor.java:53)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.common.stateguard.StateGuardAspect$1.invoke(StateGuardAspect.java:63)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy227.findAssetWithProperty(Unknown Source)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.repository.maven.internal.MavenFacetUtils.findAsset(MavenFacetUtils.java:132)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.repository.maven.internal.MavenFacetImpl.get(MavenFacetImpl.java:175)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.transaction.TransactionalWrapper.proceedWithTransaction(TransactionalWrapper.java:56)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.transaction.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:54)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.repository.maven.internal.hosted.HostedHandler.doGet(HostedHandler.java:72)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.repository.maven.internal.hosted.HostedHandler.handle(HostedHandler.java:58)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.repository.view.Context.proceed(Context.java:80)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.repository.storage.UnitOfWorkHandler.handle(UnitOfWorkHandler.java:39)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.repository.view.Context.proceed(Context.java:80)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.repository.view.handlers.ContentHeadersHandler.handle(ContentHeadersHandler.java:44)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.repository.view.Context.proceed(Context.java:80)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.repository.maven.internal.VersionPolicyHandler.handle(VersionPolicyHandler.java:60)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.repository.view.Context.proceed(Context.java:80)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.repository.view.handlers.ConditionalRequestHandler.handle(ConditionalRequestHandler.java:72)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.repository.view.Context.proceed(Context.java:80)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.repository.view.handlers.ExceptionHandler.handle(ExceptionHandler.java:43)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.repository.view.Context.proceed(Context.java:80)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.repository.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:52)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.repository.view.Context.proceed(Context.java:80)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.repository.view.handlers.TimingHandler.handle(TimingHandler.java:46)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.repository.view.Context.proceed(Context.java:80)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.repository.view.Context.start(Context.java:114)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.repository.view.Router.dispatch(Router.java:63)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.repository.view.ConfigurableViewFacet.dispatch(ConfigurableViewFacet.java:52)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.repository.view.ConfigurableViewFacet.dispatch(ConfigurableViewFacet.java:43)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.repository.httpbridge.internal.ViewServlet.dispatchAndSend(ViewServlet.java:198)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.repository.httpbridge.internal.ViewServlet.doService(ViewServlet.java:160)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.repository.httpbridge.internal.ViewServlet.service(ViewServlet.java:117)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.ServletDefinition.doServiceImpl(ServletDefinition.java:286)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.ServletDefinition.doService(ServletDefinition.java:276)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.ServletDefinition.service(ServletDefinition.java:181)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.DynamicServletPipeline.service(DynamicServletPipeline.java:71)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:85)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:112)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:82)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ProxiedFilterChain.doFilter(ProxiedFilterChain.java:61)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.executeChain(AdviceFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.doFilterInternal(AdviceFilter.java:137)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ProxiedFilterChain.doFilter(ProxiedFilterChain.java:66)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.executeChain(AdviceFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.doFilterInternal(AdviceFilter.java:137)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ProxiedFilterChain.doFilter(ProxiedFilterChain.java:66)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.executeChain(AdviceFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.doFilterInternal(AdviceFilter.java:137)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ProxiedFilterChain.doFilter(ProxiedFilterChain.java:66)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.executeChain(AbstractShiroFilter.java:449)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.security.SecurityFilter.executeChain(SecurityFilter.java:85)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter$1.call(AbstractShiroFilter.java:365)
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.doCall(SubjectCallable.java:90)
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.call(SubjectCallable.java:83)
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.DelegatingSubject.execute(DelegatingSubject.java:383)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractShiroFilter.java:362)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.security.SecurityFilter.doFilterInternal(SecurityFilter.java:101)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:82)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.repository.httpbridge.internal.ExhaustRequestFilter.doFilter(ExhaustRequestFilter.java:71)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:82)
    at com.sonatype.nexus.licensing.internal.LicensingRedirectFilter.doFilter(LicensingRedirectFilter.java:108)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:82)
    at com.codahale.metrics.servlet.AbstractInstrumentedFilter.doFilter(AbstractInstrumentedFilter.java:97)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:82)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.internal.web.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:68)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:82)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.internal.web.EnvironmentFilter.doFilter(EnvironmentFilter.java:102)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:82)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.internal.web.HeaderPatternFilter.doFilter(HeaderPatternFilter.java:98)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:82)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.DynamicFilterPipeline.dispatch(DynamicFilterPipeline.java:104)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter.doFilter(GuiceFilter.java:135)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.bootstrap.osgi.DelegatingFilter.doFilter(DelegatingFilter.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1668)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:581)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:226)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1158)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:511)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1090)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:119)
    at com.codahale.metrics.jetty9.InstrumentedHandler.handle(InstrumentedHandler.java:175)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:109)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:517)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:308)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:242)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:273)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint$2.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:75)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.produceAndRun(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.run(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:147)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:654)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:572)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.orientechnologies.common.directmemory.OByteBufferPool.acquireDirect(OByteBufferPool.java:297)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.cache.local.OWOWCache.loadFileContent(OWOWCache.java:1407)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.cache.local.OWOWCache.load(OWOWCache.java:701)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.cache.local.twoq.O2QCache.updateCache(O2QCache.java:1107)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.cache.local.twoq.O2QCache.doLoad(O2QCache.java:346)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.cache.local.twoq.O2QCache.load(O2QCache.java:291)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.paginated.base.ODurableComponent.loadPage(ODurableComponent.java:148)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.paginated.OClusterPositionMap.ceilingPositions(OClusterPositionMap.java:498)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.paginated.OClusterPositionMap.higherPositions(OClusterPositionMap.java:465)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.paginated.OPaginatedCluster.higherPositions(OPaginatedCluster.java:1618)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.OAbstractPaginatedStorage.higherPhysicalPositions(OAbstractPaginatedStorage.java:3257)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.iterator.OIdentifiableIterator.nextPosition(OIdentifiableIterator.java:323)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.iterator.ORecordIteratorClusters.hasNext(ORecordIteratorClusters.java:162)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.OCommandExecutorSQLSelect.serialIterator(OCommandExecutorSQLSelect.java:1617)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.OCommandExecutorSQLSelect.fetchFromTarget(OCommandExecutorSQLSelect.java:1566)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.OCommandExecutorSQLSelect.executeSearch(OCommandExecutorSQLSelect.java:525)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.OCommandExecutorSQLSelect.execute(OCommandExecutorSQLSelect.java:488)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.OCommandExecutorSQLDelegate.execute(OCommandExecutorSQLDelegate.java:74)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.OAbstractPaginatedStorage.executeCommand(OAbstractPaginatedStorage.java:3200)
    ... 113 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Why are you running `deploy:deploy` instead of `mvn deploy`?  Furthermore this ` Return code is: 500 , ReasonPhrase:javax.servlet.ServletExce` shows something is wrong in your nexus setup...

Comment: NullPointerException should not be caused by a misconfiguration.  However if it was,  that would be information I am seeking.   Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got to the bottom of this.  When Nexus 3 is first installed, it gives a message about the configured memory usage being less than what was physically available.

This prompted me to tune down nexus.vmoptions and restart the service.

Eventually through a long bunch of troubleshooting I realized the orient db did not have enough 'direct memory' allocated.  Basically no new blob stores, no new settings, and no uploads were possible.

I restored the default nexus.vmoptions and it is operating appropriately again.   The memory message that prompted the original change is actually logged as "WARN" if one looks closely.  It is extremely misleading.

I would also call the Nexus throwing NullPointerExceptions left and right instead of simply indicating an out of memory problem is a defect.  Hopefully someone from Sonatype reads this, since it wasted a good 4 hours to figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

may be you were missing couple of things discussed below or you were writting the query wrong:
Please check you have written correct url to the server or you didn't have access to the server or specific targeted repository or you haven't written your sql query correctly.

Comment: The sql query is generated internally by the Nexus codebase for its internal operation.   I  have nothing to do with it.   NullPointerException is not expected behavior for an access issue.   However I was logging in as admin regardless.